# How to replicate Cake's deep search with manual joins

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.4

I have the following code:

```
$current_user = $this->User->find('first', array(
    'recursive' => -1,
    'conditions' => array('User.id' => $user_id),
    'fields' => array(
        //User
        'User.id',
        //Profile
        'Profile.user_id',
        'Profile.id',
        'Profile.first_name',
        'Profile.last_name',
        'Profile.media_asset_id',
        //Profile Picture
        'MediaAsset.id'
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'profiles',
            'alias' => 'Profile',
            'type' => 'left',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Profile.user_id = User.id'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'media_assets',
            'alias' => 'MediaAsset',
            'type' => 'left',
            'conditions' => array(
                'MediaAsset.id = Profile.media_asset_id'
            )
        )
    )
));
```

And the joins work perfectly, aka, returning the User, Profile and MediaAsset. However if I allowed Cake to do this find for me it would result in this structure: (example 1)

```
User
Profile
---- MediaAsset
```

However the manual finds it as followed: (example 2)

```
User
Profile
MediaAsset
```

Is there anyway, without doing more queries I can retrieve it similar to Cake?

Thanks, Josh.

**Edit
To clarify what I am trying to achieve.
My database is going to have a lot of tables, and a lot of those tables link to User. However I do not want to retrieve all of them as it is a waste of resources.
Because of this I am specifying manual joins for queries I am running upon every request, such as the current user.

The issue is that I need to obtain the MediaAsset in Profile, which is does fine (See example 2). But Cake's nice formatting makes a lot more sense.

**To scrowler
This find results in returning everything (User, Profile, Garage, Preference, any model that  has a user_id)

```
if (!$username || !$user = $this->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array('User.username' => $username),
        'contain' => array(
            'Profile'
        )
    ))) {
    throw new NotFoundException('User not found');
}
```

Comment: Can you explain little more?

Comment: @Anubhav, written an edit. Does that help?

Comment: Are you after a nested array for MediaAsset? If so, and you don't want to use a Cake model relationship, I think you might have to write it manually... e.g. `foreach($current_user as $key => $user){ $current_user[$key]['MediaAsset'] = $this->MediaAsset->find('all', array('conditions' => array('MediaAsset.id' => $user['Profile']['media_asset_id']))); }` - however since Cake is built to do stuff like this for you, wouldn't it be better to link it via model associations?

Comment: @scrowler It is all linked.
What I am trying to get at is that I have a lot of models, and a lot of tables.
In a lot of cases I do not need Cake referencing back and forward all over the place, and providing a lot of queries that redundant to the page.

Comment: That's what the containable behaviour is for. Set containable in your model then you just put `'contain' => array(Associated, models, you, DO, want, here)` into your find call: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

Comment: @scrowler, I have tried contain in the past, however it seems to ignore it and just load everything possibly related to it. I will post the example in the main question

Comment: Did you add the containable behavior to your model?

Answer (score 0):

in my AppModel.php  i have:

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

then in model where i have the find method:

```
$rs = $this->find('all', array(
        'recursive' => -1,
        'order' => array('User.created DESC'),
        'contain' => array(
            'Profile' => array(
               'MediaAsset' => array('fields' => array('id','profile_id' .... ),
               'fields' => array('id', 'created', .... )),
        ),
    ));
```

all works without any problems, just don't forget to add 'recursive' => -1 when using contain.